# how to edit json data runtime?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, edit

i want to add the data to existing generated json data in my asp.net mvc application , what i have to do ?
means , suppose i have class Company that having list of Departments as property. but json  serialization is not able to support such kind of circular reference. so i thought how if, i get serialize the Company object first without list of Departments, then get departments for each company and then serialize this list and append data to company serialized data. i know this may be wrong way . but i have to do because of time ultimatum. please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a view model where you won't have any circular references:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<DepartmentViewModel> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

and then you would map between your model and view model (you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this) and finally return the view model to the view.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var companies = _repository.GetCompanies();
    var companiesVM = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Company>, IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>>(companies);
    return Json(companiesVM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now you no longer would have circular references and you will be able to successfully serialize the view model to JSON and you would only pass the information that is required to the view.

Comment: what is Mapper here ? how can i include it in code. is this any thirdparty utility? if yes , then is that safe to use for long time

Comment: @Lalit, it's AutoMapper and I provided a link in my answer. It is a third party mapping utility. I've been using it in production for a long time without any problems. If you don't want to use third party utilities you could always write this function yourself and copy the properties manually.

Comment: thanks a lot may be this will helpful. As you are saying this utility is trustful then definitely i am going to use it thanks.